# C different behavior of sscanf i386 vs x86_64 parsing quoted string

Tags: c, scanf, x86-64, undefined-behavior, i386

I have found strange behavior of `sscanf` parsing double quoted string on i386 machine.

My code:

```
char string[] = "\"1597821828\" \"MODIFY\" \"/fullpath/test2\"";
printf("line : %s", string);
int total;
char store_date[12] = "", store_etat_watch[24] = "", store_path[1024] = "";
printf("stores init:%s,%d , %s,%d , %s,%d \n",
       store_date, strlen(store_date),
       store_etat_watch, strlen(store_etat_watch),
       store_path, strlen(store_path));
total = sscanf(string,"%s %s %s", store_date, store_etat_watch, store_path);
printf("stores brut:%s,%d , %s,%d , %s,%d \n",
       store_date, strlen(store_date),
       store_etat_watch, strlen(store_etat_watch),
       store_path, strlen(store_path));
```

I compile it on a debian arm64 an execute it (here is my Makefile):

> CC = gcc
>
> ERROR_CFLAGS = -Wall -W -pedantic -Wextra -Werror  CFLAGS = -static -g
> -O0 $(ERROR_FLAGS) -D_REENTRANT -DLinux  LDFLAGS = $(ERROR_FLAGS)
>
> all: sscanf_test
>
> sscanf_test: sscanf_test.c    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) sscanf_test.c -o
> sscanf_test    .PHONY:clean
>
> clean:    rm -f sscanf_test

result:

> line : "1597821828" "MODIFY" "/fullpath/test2"
>
> stores init:,0 , ,0 , ,0
>
> stores brut:"1597821828",12 , "MODIFY",8 , "/fullpath/test2",17

That's the result I expect.
Then I compile it on ubuntu i386 and execute it:

result:

> line : "1597821828" "MODIFY" "fullpath/test2"
>
> stores init:,0 , ,0 , ,0
>
> stores brut:**"1597821828""MODIFY",20** , "MODIFY",8 ,"/fullpath/test2",17

The first string is not correctly parsed.
If the string doesn't begin with double quote: 'no problem'.

```
char string[]="1597821828 \"MODIFY\" \"/fullpath/test2\"";
```

result:

> line : "1597821828" "MODIFY" "/fullpath/test2"
>
> stores init:,0 , ,0 , ,0
>
> stores brut:1597821828,10 , "MODIFY",8 , "/fullpath/test2",17

I do have to parse string beginning with double quote.

Somebody can help me ?

Comment: `char store_date[12]` is too small.

Comment: Ok. Just tested. Good. Thanks a lot....but why ?

Comment: Because it cannot contain the full string withe the double quotes, as the space for the string terminator is missing.

Comment: I thought store_date[12] was enougth:

Comment: Thanks. So, how can it be correct on arm64 ? (trying to understand)

Comment: `how can it be correct on arm64 ?` Welcome to the world of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: It is wrong on all architectures. Fix it for all.

Comment: Even with a larger buffer, reading an input file with too large strings will cause your program to fail. Or: worse.

Comment: Passing results of `strlen()` to `%d` invokes *undefined behavior* because `strlen()` returns `size_t` while `%d` expects `int`. `%zu` should be used to print `size_t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char store_date[12]` is too small to store the the *string* `*1597821828*`  (Quote character replaced by `*` for clarity.).  Result: *undeifned behavior* (UB).  A string of length 12 needs at least 12+1 `char`.  The +1 is for the *null character*.

That it seemed to work on some systems is normal for UB; UB isn't "required to fail", it's "*anything* can happen".  If the memory you stepped on outside `store_data[12]` happened to not be something the compiler was using for anything needed later in the function, it can happen to work.  That's what makes undefined behaviour so nasty: testing can't always reveal it.

---

Make the destination array large enough and use widths with `"%s"`.

```
// char store_date[12]="";
// total=sscanf(string,"%s",store_date);

char store_date[12+1]="";
total=sscanf(string,"%12s",store_date);
```

---

Mis-matched specifier with `strlen()`

```
// printf("%d \n",strlen(store_path));
printf("%zu\n",strlen(store_path));
```

Comment: I am surprised that `gcc` accepts this code with the given compilation options: it should warn about the type mismatch between `%d` and `strlen()` and `-Werror` should make the compilation fail. I suspect `-O0` to prevent these useful warnings.

Comment: @chqrlie: x86-64 GCC *does* reject the OP's source code even at `-O0 -Wall -Werror`, unless you use `-m32`.  Then `size_t` = `unsigned int` and it's not a format string mismatch even with `-O3`.  https://godbolt.org/z/seYne9

Comment: @PeterCordes: compiling for ARM64 always fails too. The Makefile seems broken in the question too, which might explain this.

Comment: @chqrlie: I don't think it's very interesting to try to analyze the OP's Makefile, but yes of course it will warn / error on any target where `size_t` isn't `unsigned int`.  The warning / error isn't even for the wrong array size, so that's really just secondary to the sometimes-happens-to-work UB.  (Unless the format-string bug disturbed printing as well...)  Anyway just super-broken and both need to be fixed.  If the OP wants an asm-level explanation of exactly what happened and why, then they should post exact source and build options, and/or asm output.